# How to scroll to an element inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In HTML, usually we use # to scroll to an element with that hash as id.

For eg: We use index.php#myaccount as url to scroll to an element with id myaccount (id="myaccount")

But, how to scroll to an HTML element, if it's in an Bootstrap Tab. Because we use # to select the tab on page load.

For eg:To select a 'sales' tab on the page load, we use index.php#sales.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onclick event to select that specific tab.

Try:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#mytab">Click Here</a>

$("#mylink").click(function() {
    $('#mytab').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: thanks Django. But i have already done this. What i want to scroll to a DIV element inside the selected boostrap tab on page load.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the tab 'active', you need to set a js-function onto the button where you want to jump to your element.

```
<a id="button" href="#sales" >Click Here</a>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#sales").attr("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks Gabbax0r. But i have already done this. What i want to scroll to a DIV element inside the selected boostrap tab on page load.